# capturing image cursor returns null in android

Tags: android, cursor, image-capture

In application I am using cursorloader to get captures image file path, it always returns `null`:

```
Uri file path = file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/BBI_Images/BBI_ORIG_20150313_112912.jpg

public static int getRotation(Context context, Uri selectedImage, String filePath) {
        try{
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE };

        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(context, selectedImage, projection, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();//here i can get only null
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

        int rotation = 0;
        String realPath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
        if (realPath != null) {
            rotation = getRotationForImage(realPath);
        }
        return rotation;
        }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: is there any error thrown?

Comment: look here....the cursorLoader is not automatically created, You have to do some more work: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader--mobile-5673